# How can i change background according to category in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have 2 categories in my magento website ie "Books" and "Electronics".
I want to change the background of the website according to category.It means when i select  "Electronics" category, it will show different background than in category "Books".

Can anyone please tell how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage categories -> Custom Layout -> Custom Layout Update:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/custom_category_1.css</stylesheet>
        <params>media="all"</params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Define the custom background in the css. Override the default styling by adding !important

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using jquery

you need to go to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/

and edit view.phtml

before

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

add this code

```
<?php
if($_category->getId()==$mycatId):
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').css("background","url($imgUrl)");
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: So he should write a 100-line if/else branch to cover all his categories?

Comment: hey sulabh i have installed fortis theme,now where can i add this code?

Comment: David said he has 2 categories, i guess this would suffice.
@David I havent used fortis theme, but i guess you could find the view.phtml in app/design/frontend/fortis/default/template/catalog/category/

Answer (score 1):

Each category has a 'Custom Design' tab where you can specify certain layouts. If you only want to change the background color, it is probably easiest to create a category attribute to hold the hex value, instead.

There are several tutorials online on how to create your own category attributes. If you want a nice interface to do so, there is this extension: [DeltaCats](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/deltacats-6930.html)